# Replay audio from in-memory source

Tags: android, audio, media-player, in-memory, replay

I have some audio data (raw uncompressed audio waveform, no file format) in memory and want to replay it. Android-internal Mediaplayer seems to support only replaying of files stored somewhere on disk, I could not find a setDataSource()-method that would accept an array of data instead of a path/URL.

So how can I replay waveforms that are not stored on disk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html). See e.g. [this page](http://www.brokenteapotstudios.com/android-game-development-blog/2011/10/playing-a-wav-pcm-sample-with-audiotrack.html) for an example of how to set up an use an AudioTrack (jump to the "Playing the sample with an AudioTrack" section, and just ignore the JNI-stuff).